# Viewing which params were requested during load test

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, load-testing

I'm using Visual Studio Online Load Testing to test an API with variable parameters coming from a CSV file.

My setup looks like this:

[image]

In properties I set "Show Separate Request Results" to True, hoping that I would be able to see which parameters were used during the test, but I cannot find anything on this in the report?

Is this the way to do this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio load tests are not great at showing how individual test cases worked. The test case logs show the data source values used by a test, look in the context section of the log. By default, logs of the first 200 test cases that fail are retained; altered via `Maximum test logs` in run settings. Logs of successful tests can also be retained by altering `Save log frequency for completed tests` in run settings.

Whilst the log files have the data in their context sections, it is hard work (ie lots of mouse waving and mouse clicking) to open each log file, view the context, scroll the right section into view, close the log file, etc.

The mechanism I use to record data source usage etc is to have a web test plugin with a `PostWebTest` method. It writes useful data to a simple text file as each test case finishes. I write one line per test case, formatted as a CSV so it can easily be read and analysed in a spreadsheet. The data written includes date, time, test outcome, some data source values, and some context parameter values extracted or generated during the run. Tests run with multiple agents will get one file written on each agent. Gathering these files will be a little work but less than viewing individual test case log files. Unfortunately I have not found a way of collecting these files from load tests run with Visual Studio Team Services (previously known as Visual Studio Online).

An early version of the plugins I wrote can be found [here](http://adrianhhh.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/logging-web-test-details-to-text-file.html).

Comment: Thanks AdrianHHH, I will try your approach. I hope they improve the reporting of this tool in the future though.