# Is it possible for VS LoadTest inserting a new value into the .csv data source during the test

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing

in my Visual-Sudio loadtest, I need to run some precondition test and generate some approved id. and then these approved ids will be used to run other load test.  How do we save these approved ids?  and then I can combine these ids with my data from the .csv file to run my load test?  Can I insert these values into my .csv datasource file? how?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve. Do you really mean two load tests? Or, do you want to get a value in one webtest and use it in another, where both webtests are in the same load test. You question is much too broad and vague to be answered at present.

Comment: let's explain it in another way. in my load test, i need different approved ids for different users to run the test. I can run a small load test to generate these approved ids. this is only my precondition for other load test.  in my real load test, i will do if the user has approved id, i will use approved id to do the web request, if no approved id, I will use other items to send out the request.  Each user has one approved id and there are tons of test users.  I don't want to manually put the approved ids into the data source file. Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at using a queue solution, such as RabbitMQ, to use as an intermediary.  Most (but not all) performance testing tools will load parameter files into RAM at the beginning of the test for each user to avoid the inevitable disk conflict on multiple users trying to access and obtain lock on a disk based file.

How would this work?  Business process A creates an item.  This item is passed to a queue managed by RabbitMQ (or Amazon simple queue service, or Cloud Azure queue service, or.....).  Business process B, which uses business process A output, then reads from the queue the value required for processing.

Answer (score 0):

I have used one load test (normally at low numbers of virtual users) to prepare the data for my real load test. The data preparation test uses the normal file output routines available C# plus .Net to write the data preparation results to a text file. That output file can be CSV format so it is easily read as a datasource CSV to another test that is run later.

Normally I would have a `PostWebTest` plugin of the data preparation test append one line, in CSV format, to a file.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37046641/546871).